# Python 3.8 Snowflake Connection Error : snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250003: 250003

Tags: python, connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://ABC.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=efabf1c7-7fb6-48cb-a50e-256967e3de45&databaseName=DATAVAULT&schemaName=STAGE&warehouse=DATAVAULT&roleName=TEST_Admin&request_guid=c99547cd-ceeb-4280-845b-f2de7be76755

Getting connection error on Windows Python 3.8

Connection parameters

```
{
    "user" : "TestUser1",
    "password" : "XXXX",
    "account" : "ABC.us-east-2.aws",
    "warehouse" : "DATAVAULT",
    "database" : "DATAVAULT",
    "schema" : "STAGE",
    "Role" : "Test_role"
}
```

Also tried account name as  "ABC", "ABC.aws" but didn't work

Code:

```
    import snowflake.connector as snow

    conn = snow.connect(user=self.user,
      password= self.password,
      account= self.account,
      warehouse=self.warehouse,
          database=self.database,
      schema=self.schema,
      role=self.role
      )
    cur = conn.cursor()
```

The same code works fine from Linux but not with Windows version of Python.
Added proxy as below but didn't help

```
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = "http://http-proxy.company.com:80"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "https://http-proxy.company.com:443"
```

=====================================
Using sqlalchemy

```
import os 

os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = "http://http-proxy.xxx.com:80"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "https://https-proxy.xxx.com:443"

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
import os
import sys



url = URL(
    account = 'xxxx.us-east-2.aws',
    user = 'TestUser1',
    database = 'DATAVAULT' ,
    schema = 'STAGE',
    warehouse= 'DATAVAULT',
    role = 'DV_Admin',
    password='xxxx', # note my passsword has a '@' in it 
)
print(os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'])
print(os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'])


engine = create_engine(url)
print(engine)
results = engine.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
sys.exit()
try:
    results = engine.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()
    assert results is not None
finally:
    engine.dispose()
```

Comment: Does a simple snowsql connection from windows works fine to this SF instance?

Comment: yes it works from snowsql from the same windows machine

Comment: Can you post the connection parameters used (full command) used from snowsql?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Snowflake SnowSQL\snowsql-1.2.9-windows_x86_64>snowsql.exe -a ABC.us-east-2.aws -u TestUser1 -d DATAVAULT -s STAGE -r DV_Admin -w DATAVAULT
Password:

Comment: Can you run [**SnowCD**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) against the [**SYSTEM$WHITELIST**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html) json and see if you have any network issues?

Comment: When I run like    snowcd.exe h:\snowcd_config.json
Performing 3 checks for 1 hosts

Check for 1 hosts failed, display as follow:
==============================================
Host: XXXXX.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com
Port: 443
Type: SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT
Failed Check: Certificate Check
Error: certificate checker timeout
Suggestion: Check your connection to XXXXX.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: But when I run with Proxy It works "snowcd.exe h:\snowcd_config.json --proxyHost http-proxy.XXXX.com --proxyPort 80
Performing 1 checks for 1 hosts
All checks passed"

Comment: I added my  Proxy like in my python code

os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = "http://http-proxy.XXXX.com:80"
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "https://https-proxy.XXXX.com:443"
but no luck
Also the script works for below line

engine = create_engine(url)
print(engine)


Engine(snowflake://TestUser1:***@xxxxxx.us-east-2.aws/DATAVAULT/STAGE?role=DV_Admin&warehouse=DATAVAULT)
But fails on below line 

results = engine.execute('select current_version()').fetchone()

Comment: Error :    
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError) 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://xxxxxx.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=7079d80f-02a4-4af8-af72-4bb902b2fd82&databaseName=DATAVAULT&schemaName=STAGE&warehouse=DATA

Comment: snowcd config : [{"type":"SNOWFLAKE_DEPLOYMENT","host":"Xxxx.us-east-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com","port":443}]

Comment: snowsql command : C:\Program Files\Snowflake SnowSQL\snowsql-1.2.9-windows_x86_64>snowsql.exe -u TestUser1 -a xxxx.us-east-2.aws -w DATAVAULT -d DATAVAULT -r DV_Admin -s STAGE
Password:
* SnowSQL * v1.2.9
Type SQL statements or !help
TestUser1#DATAVAULT@DATAVAULT.STAGE>

Comment: Have you set the proxy as environment variables in Windows? Like it is mentioned [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-a-proxy-server)

Comment: After fixing the Wifi proxy and Key chain file I am able to connect from my MAC.


Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the Wifi proxy and Key chain file I am able to connect from my MAC.